# Java help creating a new socket per connected user

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, stream, connection

I am creating a chat server and i can not get more than one connection established, i believe that this is due to there being only one socket. I have read that a thread is capable of handling more than one socket connection at a time but each client must have it's own socket. like a wall outlet. There must be 1 outlet per plug. How do i create a socket for each client to use to communicate to the server? I will supply a bit of code to help you guys base your help off of. Here is where the single socket (connection) is accepted.

```
 private void waitForConnection() throws IOException
 {
     connection = server.accept();
     showMessage("\nNow connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().toString());
     clientCount += 1;
 }
```

Here is where the code is called from at server start:

```
public void startRunning()
{
  try
  {
     server = new ServerSocket(1337, 10);
     while(true)
     {
        try
        {
            showMessage("Waiting For a Player To Connect...");
            waitForConnection();
            setupStreams();
            whileChatting();

        }
        catch(EOFException eofException)
        {
           showMessage("\n Server ended the connection! ");
        }
        finally
        {
           closeConnections();
        }
     }
  }
  catch(IOException ioException)
  {
     ioException.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Now this code works perfectly for the first connected client. All others simply cant connect. Thanks in advance to all who have submitted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep a thread always executing `socket.accept()`. That is:

- Whenever you receive a client (via `socket.accept()`), you should

  - Start a new `Thread`, that will from now on take care of that client. (I'll call that `Thread` extending class `ClientNanny`);
  - and then get back to run `socket.accept()` again.

This is what your `waitForConnection()` method shoud look like:

```
private List<ClientNanny> clients = new ArrayList<ClientNanny>();

private void waitForConnection() throws IOException
{
     while (true) { /* or some other condition you wish */
         connection = server.accept(); /* will wait here */
         /* this code is executed when a client connects... */

         showMessage("\nNow connected to " 
                                      + connection.getInetAddress().toString());

         ClientNanny nanny = new ClientNanny(connection); /* call a nanny to take
                                                             care of it */
         clients.add(nanny); /* make sure you keep a ref to it, just in case */
         nanny.start(); /* tell nanny to get to work as an independent thread */
         clientCount += 1; /* you dont need this: use clients.size() now */
     }
}
```

In case you didn't notice, `ClientNanny` should be something like:

```
class ClientNanny extends Thread {
    ClientNanny(Socket baby) {
        this.myBaby = baby;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        bed.put(myBaby); /* and probably other commands :) */
    }
}
```

Now, you should notice that the highlighted code below...

```
try
{
    showMessage("Waiting For a Player To Connect...");
    waitForConnection();
    setupStreams();  /* <--------- THIS LINE! HI! I'M A HIGHLIGHT! */
    whileChatting(); /* <--------- THIS LINE! HI! I'M A HIGHLIGHT TOO! */
}
```

Will not get executed when you change `waitForConnection()` as I suggested (as `waitForConnection()` will keep on rolling inside the `while(true)` loop). Maybe you could put the `socket.accept()` on a thread of its own... Anyway, I trust you can take it from now on, yeah?

<sup>PS.: As a final pointer, the solution above uses `new Thread()` (or `new ClientNanny()` for that matter) as it is easiest way to explain your problem. The very very optimal solution, though, might involve using an `ExecutorService` (roughly, a thread pool), as quickly pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12017742/1850609).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The entire structure of your code is wrong:

```
waitForConnection();
setupStreams();
whileChatting();
```

This can't do what you require. Your loop should spin doing nothing but accept connections and then start a new thread for each one that handles all the I/O over that Socket. See the [Custom Networking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html) section of the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Your socket code should look like this PSEUDO-CODE:

```
create server socket
while true (or quit received) {
    accept connection
    spawn thread to handle communication
}
```

That is, you need to spawn a thread for each connection. Then **each thread can do the whileChatting()**, rather than holding up the main thread.

Example:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        // listen for client connections
        Socket s = svr.accept();

        // start a separate thread to handle this client's communications
        new ChatClientHandler(s).start();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // print out the error, but continue!
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```